# Get server URL from local storage to call API in Ionic(Angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic application using Angular. In **ApiService.ts** file I have logic to get API server URL from local storage. I have also defined methods for each API in this file.

Then I import ApiService on another page and call the API methods, but it executes methods first and then gets values from local storage. In that case, API_URL is empty. So does not call the API with a locally stored URL.

Following is a code

**ApiService.ts**

```
    import { EnvService } from './env.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

    @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class ApiService {

    private API_URL: string;
    private httpOptions: any;
  

    private BearerToken: any;
      private APILoading: any;
      constructor(private storage: Storage, private env: EnvService,
                  private http: HttpClient, private toastController: ToastController) {
    
          this.storage.get(this.env.COMPANY_CONFIG_STORAGE_KEY).then(res => {
            if (res) {
              this.API_URL = res.RESULT[0].APIURL;
      

      }
      });

      this.storage.get(this.env.TOKEN_KEY).then(res => {

        if (res) {
          debugger;
          this.httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-Auth-Token': res[0].TOEKN
            })
          };
        }
      });

  }
  GetDashboardDetails(flag: number, LOCID: number, OUSERID: number) {
    return this.http.get(this.API_URL + 'API/MgmtDashboard/GetDashboardDetails?FLAG='+ flag +'&LOCID='+ LOCID +'&OUSERID=' +
      OUSERID, this.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

**DashboardPage.ts**

```
import { EnvService } from './../../services/env.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart } from 'chart.js';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard-statistics',
  templateUrl: './dashboard-statistics.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard-statistics.page.scss'],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('doughnutCanvas') doughnutCanvas: ElementRef;  
  private doughnutChart: Chart;   
 
  constructor(private api: ApiService,private env: EnvService) { 

    this.api.GetDashboardDetails(0,15,120).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('GetDashboardDetails' + data);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(){


    this.doughnutChart = new Chart(this.doughnutCanvas.nativeElement, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: ['Scheduled', 'Visited', 'Visit Orders'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
              'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
              'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
            ],
            hoverBackgroundColor: ['#FF6384', '#36A2EB', '#FFCE56']
          }
        ]
      }
    });

  }


}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't retrieve the keys from local storage in the service constructor. Get them in the api method before trying to use them. Use `Promise.all()` to make sure both promises resolve before using them in your api method.

```js
import { EnvService } from './env.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  private API_URL: string;
  private httpOptions: any;
  private BearerToken: any;
  private APILoading: any;

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private env: EnvService,
    private http: HttpClient,
    private toastController: ToastController
  ) { }

  GetDashboardDetails(flag: number, LOCID: number, OUSERID: number) {

    Promise.all([
      this.storage.get(this.env.COMPANY_CONFIG_STORAGE_KEY),
      this.storage.get(this.env.TOKEN_KEY)
    ]).then((keys) => {
      this.API_URL = keys[0].RESULT[0].APIURL;
      this.httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-Auth-Token': keys[1][0].TOKEN
        })
      };
      return this.http.get(this.API_URL + 'API/MgmtDashboard/GetDashboardDetails?FLAG=' + flag + '&LOCID=' + LOCID + '&OUSERID=' + OUSERID, this.httpOptions);
    });
  }
}
```